# How to ensure atomicity with multiple transactions/updates in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I have something like:

```
Model1.update_all ['a1 = ?, a2 = ?', v1, v2], ['id = ?', id1]
Model2.update_all  ['a3 = ?', v3], ['id = ?', id2]
```

How can I ensure that if one of the above updates fails that none of them has an effect, ie. a kind of rollback is performed?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it..

```
Model1.transaction do
  Model1.update_all ['a1 = ?, a2 = ?', v1, v2], ['id = ?', id1]
  Model2.update_all  ['a3 = ?', v3], ['id = ?', id2]
end
```